# Mocking redis connection in pytest

Tags: python, redis, pytest, python-mock

I'm trying to test my app with `pytest`. The app uses Redis to store a variable, and changes to that variable are reported live to users connected with the app.

I want to create such a fixture, that will patch `Redis()` constructors in my app to connect with the local Redis database running in the background.

I've tried something like this in my `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def redis_connection():
    r_conn = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1', 6337)
    with mock.patch('app.redis_utils.redis_connect') as redis_connect_mock:
        redis_connect_mock.return_value = r_conn
        yield redis_connect_mock
    r_conn.flushdb()
```

`app.redis_utils.redis_connect` contents:

```
def redis_connect() -> Redis:
    return Redis(**settings.REDIS_SETTINGS)
```

But this fails when my app tries to access data from redis database (I call `.get()` on redis instance).

```
AssertionError: assert <MagicMock name='redis_connect.get()' id='139688062779600'> is None
```

What can I do to force `redis_connect` function to return this particular instance: `redis.Redis('127.0.0.1', 6337)`?

Comment: You probably should consider to use a redis mock library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531291/how-to-mock-a-redis-client-in-python