# how to mock redis session in python flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, redis, pytest-cov

I'm trying to test my apps using `pytest`. The app uses Redis to store a variable. with that variable, the app can determine some action.

here is my couple code to test in `app.py`

```
redis_config = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 6379,
    "db": 0,
    "charset": "utf-8",
    "decode_responses":True
}

save_redis = redis.Redis(**redis_config)

if save_redis.get("token") is None:
    //do something
else :
    //do another thing
```

the problem was the test completely running with no error but, the rest under `IF` or `else` function doesn't cover tested

I've tried in my `test_app.py`

```
save_redis = {}
def set(key, val):
    save_redis[key] = val

def get(key):
    return save_redis[key]
    
def delete(key):
    return save_redis.pop(key, None)

@mock.patch('redis.StrictRedis.get', side_effect=get)
@mock.patch('redis.StrictRedis.set', side_effect=set)
@mock.patch('redis.StrictRedis.delete', side_effect=delete)
@mock.patch('requests.post', side_effect=mocked_requests_get)
def test_check_token(self, get_mock, mock_redis_get, mock_redis_set, client):
   //do testing code
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531291/how-to-mock-a-redis-client-in-python
Maybe that?